# [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Driver Manager Message file not found. Please check for the value of InstallDir in your odbc.ini in Informatica

Tags: odbc, informatica, singlestore

I am using informatica, I have Singlestore DB which I am trying to connect.
I am able to login to singelstore DB using Singlestore ODBC Driver as below.

Singlestore version:8.0.5
SS ODBC Driver version: 1.1.1
Singlestore is self managed.

```
[abc@rnd-2 ~]$ isql SingleStore-server
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> ^C
```

While I am trying to connect informatica with Singlestore using ODBC Connection, I am gettion error:

```
Message Code: WRT_8001
Message: Error connecting to database...
WRT_8001 [Session s_test Username dev DB Error -1 
[DataDirect][ODBC lib] Driver Manager Message file not found. Please check for the value of InstallDir in your odbc.ini.
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [dev] and connection string [SingleStore-server].]Message Code: WRT_8001
Message: Error connecting to database...
WRT_8001 [Session s_test Username dev DB Error -1 
[DataDirect][ODBC lib] Driver Manager Message file not found. Please check for the value of InstallDir in your odbc.ini.
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [dev] and connection string [SingleStore-server].]
```

My location of odbc.ini file: /etc/odbc.ini

odbc.ini

```
[SingleStore_server]
Description=SingleStore server
Driver=/home/abc/singlestore-connector-odbc-1.1.1-centos7-amd64/libssodbca.so
SERVER=<>
USER=<>
PASSWORD=<>
DATABASE=<>
PORT=<>
```

I added path in .bash_profile, but still getting same error:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
```

Pls let me know how to resolve this error.

Ref link: https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/577839?language=en_US

https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/Error-connecting-to-database-DataDirect-ODBC-lib-Driver-Manager-Message-file-not-found-Please-check-for-the-value-of-InstallDir-in-your-odbc-ini-while?language=en_US

https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/developer-resources/connect-with-application-development-tools/connect-with-odbc/the-singlestore-odbc-driver.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reg `export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini`, I have seen Informatica always use their ODBC drivers. Can you please check if you have single store drivers available in `/<INFA_HOME>/ODBCX.version/odbc.ini​` file? If yes, i highly recommend to use it.
If yes, please see if you can test the ODBC driver with Infa provided tool `$INFA_HOME/tools/debugtools/ssgodbc -d dsn -u username -p password [-v]` against your DB. This will ensure you have no issues with ODBC setup.
You can find all about this here [link](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/000097328?language=en_US).

If no, then, pls make sure you have installed correct version single store ODBC drivers (32 or 64 bit) and Informatica user have RWX permission on them. Then,

1. Add the driver path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$HOME/server_dir:$ODBCHOME/lib;`
2. set `ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini`
3. grant access - `chmod 777 /etc/odbc.ini`
4. see if the tool `ssgodbc` is able to establish connection.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following examples of integrating SingleStore data with Informatica:

JDBC - https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/singlestore-jdbc-informatica-cloud.rst

ODBC - https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/singlestore-odbc-informatica.rst